# Sage evolution with branch accounting in flowgear

Tags: flowgear

I have one question regarding to flowgear with sage evolution(branching) integration.
I have created flowgear workflow for client and stkitem data sync with branch accounting(specific Branch id) to my web porter.
when i submit order from web to flowgear using specific client and stkitem data at that time sage evolution node giving the error

**Record (Customer: THR001C) cannot be used in this context as it is linked to branch 'CH'. Current branch is 'Global'.**

My sage evolution node source XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Documents xmlns="http://flowgear.net/Schemas/PastelEvolution/Documents.xsd">
  <Configuration>
    <DocumentType>ArSalesOrders</DocumentType>
    <ProcessAllOrNone>1</ProcessAllOrNone>
  </Configuration>
  <Document>
    <ProcessAction>Create</ProcessAction>
    <Account>AFR099T</Account>
    <ExternalOrderNo>12543</ExternalOrderNo>
    <OrderNo>123</OrderNo>
    <Description>Test</Description>
    <DetailLines>
      <DetailLine>
        <LineAction>Add</LineAction>
        <StockItem>TPJ057</StockItem>
        <Quantity>20.0</Quantity>
        <UnitSellingPrice>0.0</UnitSellingPrice>
        <Warehouse>CH/CA</Warehouse>
      </DetailLine>
    </DetailLines>
  </Document>
</Documents>
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an Evolution issue rather than an integration issue. Have you tried capturing this exact order manually in Evolution to see whether it errors out in the same way?

Comment: Yes i try this same order data in manually in Evolution.it is successfully inserted.Please help me